# Refactor the if...else block to use a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, refactoring

My answer is not working according to the code challenge specifications.

[image: error message from code challenge]

```
let favoritePhrase = 'Love That!';



 if (favoritePhrase === 'Love That!') {
   console.log('I love that!');
 } else {
   console.log("I don't love that!");
 }

// My refactored code  below
favoritePhrase ? console.log('I love that!') : console.log("I don't love that!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are just checking if `favoritePhrase` is not falsy. You want to check if it is equal to `'Love That!'`.

```
favoritePhrase === 'Love That!' ? console.log('I love that!') : console.log("I don't love that!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value of favoritePhrase:

```
favoritePhrase === 'Love That!' ? console.log('I love that!') : console.log("I don't love that!");
```

In your code, `favoritePhrase ?` was evaluating to true because it is a non-falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

In the ternary operator you are just checking if the variable evaluates to `true`, and not if it is equal to `Love That!`... so you need to switch from:

```
favoritePhrase ? console.log('I love that!') : console.log("I don't love that!");
```

to

```
favoritePhrase === 'Love That!' ? console.log('I love that!') : console.log("I don't love that!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to check if the value is equal to 'I Love that'

```
(favoritePhrase === 'Love That!') ? console.log('I love that!') : console.log("I don't love that!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The real use for a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is to return an expression, like the wanted string.

```js
let favoritePhrase = 'Love That!';

console.log(favoritePhrase === 'Love That!'
    ? 'I love that!'
    : "I don't love that!"
);
```